# Conditional based on the User Role of the Current Profile the user is viewing - BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress, user-roles, conditional-tags, profiles

I'm using BuddyPress and need a certain block of code to show up on user role Store Owner profiles only. I'll be putting it in member_header.php, so it's just a template file.

I've been digging for a long time now and just can't seem to figure this out. I found a way to target *current* user role, but that makes it show up on everyone's profile for a user in the Store Owner user role.

I understand I need a conditional, but I just can't seem to find the *right* conditional... Am I missing something, somehow?

Thanks so much!!

### **Edit**:

OK, so I've been fiddling around and moved on to something a little different... I still need similar help, just in a slightly different and less flexible setting.

I've changed my mind and moved this block of code to a separate profile page entirely. I have the page built and linked to in the profile menu. So what I need the conditional for is to show this menu item based on the user role of the profile being viewed.

Here's the code that works and shows up on every single user's page:

```
// Set up Custom BP navigation
function my_setup_nav() {    
   global $bp;
      bp_core_new_nav_item( array(
            'name' => __( 'Calendar', 'buddypress' ),
            'slug' => 'calendar',
            'position' => 20,
            'screen_function' => 'calendar_template' 
      ) );

      // Change the order of menu items
      $bp->bp_nav['messages']['position'] = 100;
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'my_setup_nav' );
```

Here's the code that I've been playing with, but it causes the menu item to just not show up *anywhere*.

```
// Set up Custom BP navigation
function my_setup_nav() {   
   if(user_can($user->ID, "store_owner")) {   
   global $bp;
      bp_core_new_nav_item( array(
            'name' => __( 'Calendar', 'buddypress' ),
            'slug' => 'calendar',
            'position' => 20,
            'screen_function' => 'calendar_template' 
      ) );

      // Change the order of menu items
      $bp->bp_nav['messages']['position'] = 100;
}
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'my_setup_nav' );
```

My site is: http://www.pureplayhaven.com  And the user "sample" is a "Store Owner" user.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please post the code you are trying to use.

Comment: Currently, I don't have any code I'm using. Nothing has worked so I keep deleting and retrying.

I'm just trying to insert `<h2>Hi, I'm a Store Owner!</h2` right now. Eventually I think I'm going to have to do an execute_shortcode function for the static info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check if the *displayed user* has that role, try replacing `$user->ID` with `bp_displayed_user_id()`:

```
function my_setup_nav() {   
   if ( user_can( bp_displayed_user_id(), 'store_owner' ) ) {
       // ... rest of your code
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. THAT'S IT. THANK YOU SO MUCH. YOU ARE SO INCREDIBLY AWESOME.